# AMPScript - HTML Formatting for Dynamic Table (Issues with Outlook 2013, 2016 Windows 7 and 2019)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, html

I have an email where I need to display tiles dynamically based on conditions. Maximum 8 tiles need to be shown with maximum 2 tiles in 1 row. I have created only 2 tables for the tiles and have written for loop. Now, everything seems to work fine except when its only 1 tile. In case of 1 tile, its getting slightly shifted to right, however, in case of 3,5,7 tiles, everything is fine.

```
<table cellpadding="17" class="qe_none" width="250px">

%%[ for @counter = 1 to @count do IF MOD(@counter,2) != "0" THEN TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row1= Row(@package',@counter, ',', @countername,')]%', '%' ) ) TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row2= Row(@package',@counter, ',', @counterprice,')]%', '%' ) ) TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row3= Row(@package',@counter, ',', @counterdate,')]%', '%' ) ) SET @name1 = Field(@row1,1) SET @price1 = Field(@row2,1) SET @date1 = Field(@row3,1) ]%%

<tr>

<td align="left" class="Zero" style="padding: 30px 30px 0px 0px;" valign="top" width="250px">
<table cellpadding="25" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="border-collapse: collapse; display:flex;" width="250px">

<tr>
<td align="left" style="background:#ffffff; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;color:#4a4a4a;font-size:16px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; padding-right:0px;" valign="top" width="250px">
<span><b>%%=V(@name1)=%%</b><br>
Nächste Abrechung: %%=V(@date1)=%%<br>
Monatl. Kosten: %%=V(@price1)=%%</span></td></tr></table><img alt="" src="http://image.mailing.sky.de/lib/fe38117075640474721472/m/1/93644f5f-ccc7-4260-bff0-1b2ff54c8808.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 0px; align:left; vertical-align: top;" width="245"></td><td class="Zero" style="padding: 30px 30px 0px 0px;" width="250px">
<table cellpadding="25" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="background:#fff; border-collapse: collapse; display:flex;" width="250px">
%%[IF @counter < @count THEN SET @dummycounter = ADD(@counter,"1") IF CONCAT('@flag',@dummycounter) != "0" THEN TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row4= Row(@package',@dummycounter, ',', @countername,')]%', '%' ) ) TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row5= Row(@package',@dummycounter, ',', @counterprice,')]%', '%' ) ) TreatAsContent( Concat('%','%[SET @row6= Row(@package',@dummycounter, ',', @counterdate,')]%', '%' ) ) SET @name2 = Field(@row4,1) SET @price2 = Field(@row5,1) SET @date2 = Field(@row6,1) ]%%
<tr>
<td align="Left" style="background:#ffffff; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;color:#4a4a4a;font-size:16px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" valign="top" width="250px">
<span><b>%%=V(@name2)=%%</b><br>
Nächste Abrechung: %%=V(@date2)=%%<br>
Monatl. Kosten: %%=V(@price2)=%%</span></td></tr>%%[ENDIF ENDIF]%%</table>%%[IF @counter < @count THEN]%% <img alt="" src="http://image.mailing.sky.de/lib/fe38117075640474721472/m/1/93644f5f-ccc7-4260-bff0-1b2ff54c8808.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 0px;align:left; vertical-align: top;" width="245">%%[ENDIF]%%</td></tr>%%[ ENDIF next @counter ]%%</table>
```

Comment: may I ask you why you putting px in the width attribute value? You need per cent sign value is not pixels. That's it! 
Also, your numbers don't stick together, your embedded `Table` is 250 pixels wide, but the parent `td` is 250 pixels wide and the padding is added too.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but could you be please more specific with the values ? The above code is perfectly working for all scenarios except in case of 1 tile to be shown. So, I need to be cautious while making changes as I don't want atleast my working scenarios to get distorted with my changes